# How to pack a snap which accesses a usb device

Tags: usb, snap

I'm trying to pack an application into a snap which accesses a USB device as a non-root user using libusb (usb-serial). Without any usb-specific options I reached the point that I had to chown my device to be able to use it. I think a corresponding udev rule which adds sets a group for the device (let's say "plugdev"), would have a similar effect.

Now, to continue building a proper snap which doesn't need such tricks, I read https://kyrofa.com/posts/ros-production-obtaining-confined-access-to-the-turtlebot-4-5, but the article was quite confusing. Obviously, I have to `snapcraft push` my not-yet-ready package to be able to test if it even works?
And the document talks about a section `plugs` with an `interface: serial-port`, but also about `slots`. But when defining both, I get errors from snapcraft that this combination is not allowed. Also, the final `snapcraft.yaml` listing doesn't contain the `slots` directive which was mentioned earlier. Then, there seem to be important differences between differnt `confinement` values.

Is there a 'more official' document about using USB devices than the link above? Or a nice example to copy from?

Answer (score 0):

- Check [Snapcraft.io](https://snapcraft.io/docs/serial-port-interface) docs, it is the upstream project. However, snap is still evolving so documentation lag behind current code releases.
- So read directly, interfaces/plugins code from https://github.com/snapcore/snapd to know non documented features.
- HowTo use, search for resent `snapcraft.yaml` on open source code repositories.